# Magento: Create coupon code rule that discount differently base on the current discount of items in cart

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

The requirements are if the items are already on discount, then discount extra x%, if the items are not on discount, then discount y%. I need to handle the case that both type of these above items appear in the same cart? Is there a existing solutions, or if I need to implement myself, where would I start. Thank you

Comment: Your have to make custom total for performing this type of discount or create new action in backend which is related to your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event in magento,

**sales_quote_collect_totals_after**
This is fired whenever your total is calculated, what you can do is set a flag in session on click on the button to apply discount, and in this above event's observer method, check if it is set then apply discount.

In your **config.xml**

```
<global>
 <events>
   <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
     <observers>
       <class>Custom_Module_Model_Observer</class>
       <method>collectTotals</method>
     </observers>
   </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
 </events>
</global>
```

Make a **Observer.php** in

```
Custom
  /Module
    /Model
      /Observer.php
```

Make a function in Observer.php

```
public function collectTotals(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
       $quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
       $quoteid=$quote->getId();
    //check condition here if need to apply Discount
        if($disocuntApply) $discountAmount =5;

     if($quoteid) {
               if($discountAmount>0) {
           $total=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
           $quote->setSubtotal(0);
           $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

           $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
           $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

           $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
           $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);


           $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual()? ('billing') : ('shipping'); 
           foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {

                    $address->setSubtotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                    $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                    $address->collectTotals();

                    $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());

                    $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );
                    $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(
                        (float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
                    );

                    $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                    $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());

           $quote ->save(); 

              $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
              ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
              ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
              ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal()-$discountAmount)
              ->save(); 


            if($address->getAddressType()==$canAddItems) {

             $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
             $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
             $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()-$discountAmount);
             $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal()-$discountAmount);
             if($address->getDiscountDescription()){
             $address->setDiscountAmount(-($address->getDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
             $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription().', Amount Waived');
             $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount()-$discountAmount));
             }else {
             $address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
             $address->setDiscountDescription('Amount Waived');
             $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
             }
             $address->save();
            }//end: if
           } //end: foreach
           //echo $quote->getGrandTotal();

          foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
                         //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
                         $rat=$item->getPriceInclTax()/$total;
                         $ratdisc=$discountAmount*$rat;
                         $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
                         $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount()+$ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();

                       }


                    }

            }
         }
```

**collectTotals** function will be called, whenever the quote totals is updated, so there is no need to call it explicitly.

Check for how it works here.

Setting magento session variables, check [here](http://hhttp://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-set-retrieve-and-unset-session-variables-in-magento/ttp://).

hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, can you explain a bit please. I saw `$quote->setSubtotal(0)` and `$address->setSubtotal(0)`, and later on, you have `$quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());` It is not quite intuitive for me, as the `getSubtotal()` on both `$quote` and `$address` will both be `0`. Can you explain on why you are doing this?

Comment: would you please explain some of my above question please. I would greatly appreciated it. Thank you very much

Comment: To update the order total i have first store subtotal in $total variable and than i set subtotal zero to handle right calculation